# Install app on test users

Tags: iphone, ios, installation

I recently finished my app development and now I need to test it with fair amount of users. So I want to install it on my friends devices. It will be hard work to manually install the app from my Macbook on each device, So Is there a way to let them install the app themselves? Maybe send them a link or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [TestFlight App](http://testflightapp.com/) to automate the process of sending builds via email so your beta testers can click on a link and install the app directly on the device. You will however need to add their Device UUID's initially to your signing certificate for each build

Answer (score 2):

You may use TestFlight service https://testflightapp.com.

This is a free service that allows you to define a test user base, inform & invite them and to distribute your app quite easily for them to be tested.

The basic logic is the same as Apple's, but it is just very easy to learn and use - even testers that are truly "normal" users of iPhone can easily be invited and start testing your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial on distributing builds to your testers:

[How to Host a Beta Test](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

They only way I think they would be able to do that is by having their devices registered on your Apple Developers account and they will need the provisioning licenses given by you.
Then once they have the project they can upload it to their device if they have a Macintosh.